# Bootstrap grid won't work using xs columns

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, grid, bootstrap-4

I started a new project on Codepen and I'm using bootstrap.. It's been a while since I worked CSS. The grid sistem is not responding for me, I can't find the problem. I even copied a working older proyect and didn't work neither..

Here is the pen: http://codepen.io/Chantun/pen/NjgpaY

Here's the html:

```
<body>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-offset-3 col-xs-6">
      <h1>FFC Calculator</h1> 

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Here's the CSS:

```
body {
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 60px;
  font-family: Arimo, 'Roboto Slab', serif;
  background-color: #1a3a50;
  text-decoration:none;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}

h1 {
  position: relative;
  font-family: Pacifico, 'roboto slab', serif;
  font-size: 5vw;
}
```

And here's the stuff in head:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<meta name="description" content="FCC calculator">
<meta name="keywords" content="FFC, calculator, Free, Codecamp">
<meta name="author" content="Santiago F. Rey">
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Slab:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The pen is using Bootstrap 4, and the CSS class names have changed. The `xs` infix has been removed in 4.x...

`col-xs-offset-3` is now `offset-3`
`col-xs-6` is now `col-6`

```
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="offset-3 col-6">
      <h1>FFC Calculator</h1> 
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JNyqWX

Comment: good answer, although i suggest not using BS 4 because it's still in alpha mode :)

Comment: Alpha [doesn't stop people from using it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bootstrap-4) and preparing for the beta release.

Answer (score 2):

You are using Bootstrap 4. The class names that you are using are for Bootstrap 3. So you have two options:

> - Include Bootstrap 3 in your project and remove bootstrap 4.
> - Change the class names in your code. Check [this link](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/layout/grid/#offsetting-columns) for offsets in Bootstrap 4 and [this one](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/migration/#grid-system) for grid.

This is your code for Bootstrap 4. Also take care of `col-md-x`, `col-lg-x` based on your sceen sizes.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 offset-3">
      <h1>FFC Calculator</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Also check [your CodePen link](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KmvLzr) where I have fixed it.